# How to design olx bottom navigation bar in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

[olx bottom navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W9Ys.jpg)

How can i design this bottom navigation bar of olx. Refer to above link for olx navigation bar image.  I have designed following bottom navigation bar and increased size of middle icon and also overrided  "design_bottom_navigation_height" in dimens.xml file, but what Iam getting is this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RI33.png)

It increases spacing between other icons and texts. How can I correct it?

This is my activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) navView.getChildAt(0);

        final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(2).findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.navigation_bar_item_icon_view);
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iconView.getLayoutParams();
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        // set your height here
        layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 52, displayMetrics);
        // set your width here
        layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 52, displayMetrics);
        iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_exchange, R.id.navigation_post,R.id.navigation_chat,R.id.navigation_account)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);



}

}
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not meant to tell you how to do everything. It's meant to help you past problems you've encountered. Have you tried anything to implement this bar and run into problems?

Comment: I have edited the question again and added my code that I have tried you can check it now